# Psalm 141:7 - Whose bones scattered at the mouth of Sheol?

Tags: psalms

Amplified Bible - AMP 1987 [read](https://www.bible.com/bible/8/PSA.141.AMPC)

> Psalm 141:7 The unburied bones [**of slaughtered rulers**] shall lie
>   scattered at the mouth of Sheol, [as unregarded] as the lumps of soil
>   behind the plowman when he breaks open the ground.

Amplified Bible [read](https://www.bible.com/bible/1588/PSA.141.AMP)

> Psalm 141:7 As when the one plows and breaks open the ground [and the
>   soil scatters behind him], **Our** bones have been scattered at the mouth
>   of Sheol [by the injustices of the wicked].

ESV Bible [read](https://www.bible.com/bible/59/PSA.141.ESV)

> Psalm 141:7 As when one plows and breaks up the earth, so shall **our** bones be
>   scattered at the mouth of Sheol.

So does "our" = "slaughtered rulers"? or the AMP 1987 mistranslated this verse? Who is "us" that "our bones be scattered at the mouth of Sheol"?

Comment: The translation can also be 'scattered around the grave' with the concept that God has not let someone 'rest in peace' but has disturbed their 'rest' and 'pursued them to the brink of death'. And beyond. There is a hint of 'thou shalt no leave my soul in hades'. Very figurative. Very passionate.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/psalms/141-7.htm), the majority of translations say "our" bones.

In context, David is praying that he will stand firm in following God's ways in spite of the wicked. As @Nigelj notes, David is using strong imagery to depict how the righteous are mistreated by the wicked.

In some ancient cultures, failing to receive proper burial prevented the dead from entering the Grave (Sheol, Hades, et al.) David seems to allude to this particular abuse. In addition, he portrays the wicked as callously scattering the bones of the righteous as they on their way, showing complete indifference to the plight of their victims.

Comment: So AMP 1987 mistranslated this verse and "our" = "of rightous" in contrast to "of slaughtered rulers" (as I understand "rulers" means "their judges" from 141:6, thus slaughtered rulers are wicked, thus AMP 1987 wrongly translated this verse).

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that the majority of modern experts came to a different conclusion.